# I am trying to build code with an older version of chisel

Tags: chisel

I am trying to build code with an older version of chisel.
So far I have been able to pull the older version (2.3) of the source and make it into a .jar file that I placed in the source directory and the .ivy/cache directory, and edited the "build.sbt" file to add a line:
    libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel" % "2.3-SNAPSHOT"

But when I do sbt run I get:

```
[warn]  module not found: edu.berkeley.cs#chisel_2.11;2.3-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /root/.ivy2/local/edu.berkeley.cs/chisel_2.11/2.3-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/berkeley/cs/chisel_2.11/2.3-SNAPSHOT/chisel_2.11-2.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: edu.berkeley.cs#chisel_2.11;2.3-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      edu.berkeley.cs:chisel_2.11:2.3-SNAPSHOT (Local build Path)
[warn]        +- default:chisel_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy the jar to the ivy cache directory, other meta information are required for ivy/sbt to use the jars in the cache. Copy the jar to 'lib' directory in your project folder. This is called "unmanaged dependencies" in sbt jargon. For more info see the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html). Curiously, may I ask why are you trying to use an "older" version of Chisel in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the help--

Comment: Our software is using a number of features of "chisel2" that have been been depreciated (for example fill()) and we have been told that there are new ways to do this but there doesn't yet seem to be any documentation on replaces for these functions. Also, as our code is finished and working as of the end of June we are not looking forward to rewriting the code, or rewriting it every time the compiler is updated...

Comment: Hi, Just a note as to my final solution. I was able to add  autoScalaLibrary := false
libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel" % "2.2.33"           to my build.sbt file to include only the library version I wanted. This avoided having to build my one copy of the chisel library.